# Repping the Editors

Tags: support, editing, reputation

Is there a way for me to rep people for edits that I like to my posts? I especially want this myself because the community might like me more if I am able to reward those who typeset my posts.

Comment: Yes. Pay it forward. Help make this site a site where these users are happy to stay. That means voting more often, editing other posts, and generally improving the site. It's not all about reputation, it's about the will to return, and while reputation has some sort of "sunken cost fallacy" to it, it doesn't last very long. It's the fact the site is *fun* that brings people back on a consistent and large scale. You want to reward your editors? Help make the site a better place for them to return to the next time they visit.

Comment: If the person who edited the question has less than 2K rep they actually gain some rep when the edit is approved, I don't recall if it was 2 or 5 points. Anyway, I second Asaf here. It costs nothing to upvote stuff, and it tells people that they are welcome here. Upvote anything you like - I think that's the point of it. It's not about the rep, it's about feeling welcome (that's what it keeps me coming back, at least).

Comment: Or... *Bright lights flashing*  **bingo!**...stop waiting for (even expecting)  others to edit/format your un-formatted posts , and learn mathjax so you can format your own posts!  You've asked/answered enough questions at MSE that you've reached the point where there is *no excuse* for not adopting and using mathjax.

Comment: @amWhy I have better things to do than wait around to have people format my posts. However look at my last post: it had perfect mathjax formatting.

Comment: @amWhy I did not format it but it has perfect formatting even without an editor.

Comment: @amWhy Did you downvote my topology question? If so plz give feedback.

Comment: I haven't read or downvoted any of your topology questions, so I can assure you: NO